# Как работает ключевое слово static

Tags: php

Имеем 2 примера

**Первый:**

```
function a()
{
    static $number = 0;
    echo "[".$number."]";
    $number++;
    echo "-[".$number."]\n";
}
a();
a();
a();
```

В результат:

`[0]-[1]
 [1]-[2]
 [2]-[3]`

**Второй**

```
$digit = 10;
function a()
{
    static $number = 0;
    echo "[".$number."]";
    $number = &$GLOBALS["digit"];
    $number++;
    echo "-[".$number."]\n";
}
a();
a();
a();
```

Результат:

`[0]-[11]
 [0]-[12]
 [0]-[13]`

Мне непонятно почему так происходит когда мы не используем ссылку то все работает как и ожидается, но когда мы используем ссылку статическая переменная обнуляется?
Я хочу просто понять почему это так работает!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Переменная - это именованная область памяти (имя переменной и область памяти на которое это имя ссылается). Статические переменные - это специальные переменные с измененной областью видимости. Причем признак того, что переменная статическая определено в ее области памяти. Пока вы при помощи имени `$number` пользуетесь статической областью памяти все нормально. Как только вы ссылаетесь при помощи ссылки на другую область памяти, вы имеете дело уже с другим значением.

Посмотрите на этот код

```
<?php
$digit = 10;
function a()
{
    static $number = 0;
    $number++;
    echo "[".$number."]";
    $number = &$GLOBALS["digit"];
    echo "-[".$number."]\n";
}
a();
a();
a();
```

В результате будет выведено

```
[1]-[10]
[2]-[10]
[3]-[10]
```

Пока вы оперируете изначальной областью памяти `$number` - все нормально, переменная ведет себя как статическая. Когда вы **имени** `$number` назначаете другую область памяти - это фактически другая переменная с другими свойствами.

```
<?php
$digit = 10;
function a()
{
    static $number = 0;
    $number++;
    echo "[".$number."]";
    $number = &$GLOBALS["digit"]; // Здесь связь со static разорвана
    $number += 2;
    echo "-[".$number."]\n";
}
a();
a();
a();
```

Результат

```
[1]-[12]
[2]-[14]
[3]-[16]
```

Т.е. результат из первой колонки вообще никак не связан с результатом из второй - это разные области памяти, со своими собственными значениями. Просто при помощи одной и той же ссылки вы можете ссылаться попеременно, то на одну, то на другую область памяти. В PHP ручное управление ссылками не так нужно и очевидно, как скажем в C или C++, но это очень важно, так как позволяет вам не копировать гигантские массивы данных, а лишь передавать ссылку на них. В отличие от C/C++ в 99% случаев PHP самостоятельно передает объемные данные по ссылке, вам крайне редко требуется напрямую прибегать к оператору &.

Comment: Ну так ссылка это ведь псевдоним какой-либо другой переменной, которая ссылается на одно и то же значение так? Получается когда мы  делаем ссылку для переменной `static` мы ссылаемся на другую область видимости и значение и казалось бы это очевидно, но то что переменная меняет свойства это странно, причем все возвращается на круги своя при новом вызове этой функции и переменная обладает своими прежними свойствами `static`.
Кстати в документации к области видимости есть раздел и там приводятся примеры на `global` и `static`.

Comment: Но что примечательное механизм `global` описан, а вот `static` не понятно на чем основывается и почему он так поступает...забавная ситуация описана в unset когда удаляют `static` переменную

Comment: можно обсудить с вами некоторые вопросы в чате?

Comment: @MaximPro да, конечно, инициируйте его пожалуйста еще раз, в будни не было возможности поддержать беседу в чате.